# YouTube embedded video auto loop without refresh screen

Tags: loops, video, iframe, youtube

I want to show a video which starts to run automatically and loops infinitely in my adobe portfolio website. I tried using YouTube embedded video with autoplay and loop options (see below code), however, every time the video ends there is a black refresh screen before it starts again which ruins the appearance of my website. The video format I'm using is `.mp4`. I know that with `.gif` file this problem can be solved, however, the video quality will not be sufficient. I tried downloading the video into the portfolio website directly, however, I couldn't make it loop or autoplay.

I would appreciate your help in this matter.
Thanks, Tal

The code:

```
<iframe width="1920" height="1080"
     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/youtubelink?rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=0&loop=1&playlist=youtubelink&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" 
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> 
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 6):

After some research I've finally got it working, the solution is to use the API iframe embed code (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and instead of using the loop parameter you make use of the `onPlayerStateChange` function. Here is a code example:

```
                  <div id="player"></div>
                    <script>
                      var tag = document.createElement('script');
                      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                      var player;
                      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                        player = new YT.Player('player', {
                            videoId: '<?php the_field('homepage_video_background_id'); ?>',
                            playerVars: {
                                modestbranding: 0,
                                autoplay: 1,
                                controls: 0,
                                showinfo: 0,
                                wmode: 'transparent',
                                branding: 0,
                                rel: 0,
                                autohide: 0,
                                origin: window.location.origin
                            },
                            events: {
                                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                            }
                          });
                        }
                        function onPlayerReady(event) {
                            event.target.playVideo();
                        }
                        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                player.playVideo(); 
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

This method still flashes an instant black screen before restarting the video. If you need a smoother loop use this;

```
'onStateChange': function (event) {
           var YTP=event.target;
           if(event.data===1){
                var remains=YTP.getDuration() - YTP.getCurrentTime();
                if(this.rewindTO)
                    clearTimeout(this.rewindTO);
                this.rewindTO=setTimeout(function(){
                     YTP.seekTo(0);
                 },(remains-0.1)*1000);
             }
 }
```

Comment: That is a fantastic solution...although there is s very very slight pause...it's a much better solution to the black/blank flicker. Thank you so much! Do you happen to know how to remove the black/blank flicker on very first load? and possibly remove the Loading spinner...?

Comment: Instant playing is not possible with any kind of youtube solution. Users still need to wait for youtube  scripts and data to load. But if you want to hide the spinner you use the API events and detect when video loaded and ready to play.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out this problem myself. I'm currently using **Adobe Portfolio**.

Are we allow to add  code within the Embed box?