# Remove black loading screen from YouTube embed looped video

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I've checked out the other threads about this, but couldn't really find what I'm after.

I've embedded a **YouTube** video in **iFrame** form. It's set to autoloop. Here's the parameters:

`?showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=0&playlist=SeFzUzde5BM`

The problem is that before the video starts, there's a black screen with a loading bar. That in itself isn't too bad, but then when the video goes to loop, it does that again! Why does it need to load itself twice? Is there anyway to have it seamlessly loop, without the loading screen breaking up each loop?

Comment: Please see related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635316/youtube-embedded-video-auto-loop-without-refresh-screen/52931895#52931895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jimmy's solution looks good. I ended up using an HTML video player, but if anyone is curious, this is the solution that was working for me when I was using the iframe.

I had to know the time of the video (15s) and set it to loop .1s before that (14.9s). Otherwise, there'd be a little "blip" effect. I used an interval to constantly check the time. If there's a way to dynamically hook into the 0.1s spot before video end, I'd recommend that, but I couldn't find that. I also use a little fade effect so the transition is smoother.

```html
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: YOUR_ID_HERE,
          playerVars: {
            controls: 0,
            showinfo:0,
            rel:0,
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();

        var interval_is_stopped = false;
        setInterval(function (){
          var current_time = event.target.getCurrentTime();

          if (current_time > 14.9 && !interval_is_stopped) {
            interval_is_stopped = true;
            jQuery('#player').fadeTo(400, 0.7, function(){
              player.seekTo(0);
              jQuery(this).fadeTo(400, 1, function(){
                interval_is_stopped = false;
              });
            });
          }
        }, 10);

      }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be answered here:

[YouTube embedded video auto loop without refresh screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635316/youtube-embedded-video-auto-loop-without-refresh-screen)

However if that link becomes un-available the answer is using a Youtube Embed Api code. called `player.getPlayerState()` .You basically check that the video has "ended" and then run the `.playVideo();` function. which starts it again immediately.

[Youtube API : focused on Playback Status](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status)

I added this 'if' statement to the code provided at the top of the Youtube API page.

```
if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        player.playVideo(); 
    }
```

NOTE: As you can see you have to set it up as a separate script first instead of running it in-line in the html (it's easier to keep track of too). I suggest looking at the YouTube API linked above for extra help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19082826)

Comment: Just trying to help. If it accomplishes that i am happy. thanks for the edits david' i see what you mean though.. if the web address changes.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I ended up using an HTML player, but I just posted what ended up working for me, using iFrame. The problem with your method is it can sometimes create a "blip" at the end, depending on the video.